# Flutter run --release crash: terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc

Tags: dart, flutter

flutter run --release fails with:

```
Initializing gradle...                                              1.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2.1s
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'         
  what():  std::bad_alloc                                               
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -6                        
Snapshotting exited with non-zero exit code: -6                         
Running Gradle task 'assembleProfile'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleProfile'... Done                      97.3s
Gradle task assembleProfile failed with exit code 1
mwpierce63@mwpierce63-HP-Z600-Workstation:~/Dropbox/Flutter/diet
```

flutter doctor -v output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /home/mwpierce63/bin/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/mwpierce63/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/mwpierce63/bin/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /home/mwpierce63/bin/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
    • IntelliJ at /home/mwpierce63/intelij/idea-IC-181.4668.68
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM T320          • 08e8d4370683f6e6 • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
    • SAMSUNG SM N900A • 43fe4f65         • android-arm • Android 5.0 (API 21)
    • ASUS ZenFone 2E  • F8AZCY10U314     • android-x86 • Android 5.0.1 (API 21)

• No issues found!
```

flutter run --debug works correctly, flutter run --profile crashes with same errors above.

Any ideas?

Snippet of offending code which causes endless loop is there:

```
          subObjs = recipeObjs.elementAt(idx).findElements('Serv');
//      the problem is here
      recipes.elementAt(idx).servings =
  int.tryParse(subObjs.elementAt(0).getAttribute("qty")) ?? 1;
```

Comment: What device did you try to run on?

Comment: I tried on samsung galaxy note 3 and Samsung tablet SM T320.

Comment: OK a bit more information here. When I compile and watch my system memory usage I see it dwindle as it is allocated for the compile until I run out of system memory at which time the bad_alloc occurs. I've been looking at cyclic dependencies, found a few, and restructured code to get rid of them. There are a few more in there that I can eliminate but my question is: could the symptoms I'm seeing be caused by cyclic dependencies that the Dart compiler does not detect?

Comment: Not sure what dependencies you are talking about. Dart imports can have cyvles and they should not cause issues.

Comment: Well, I've turn gradlew build with --debug, --info, --stacktrace, --full-stacktrace and I can't get any information as to why the build is consuming all of my system memory before erroring out. Something in the --release and --profile compiles is in an endless loop (probably recursive) but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get that information.

Comment: When I run the build manually via gradlew I see it quickly get to 36% where it stays for about 2 minutes while consuming memory. A --debug release completes successfully, probably because the code is not fully compiled AOT to allow for debugging. My suspicion is that there is some sort of circular dependency that can't be fully resolved by a compile but which can be left mosty in symbolic form for interpretation during a debug run.

Comment: Found the offending statement. It runs without problem from IDE and when in debug release, but causes endless loop which consumes all memory when compiled for as profile or release build:
this.recipes.elementAt(idx).servings =
          int.tryParse(subObjs.elementAt(0).getAttribute("qty")) ?? 1;

Comment: That would be a serious compiler bug that should be reported. The statement doesn't look special or complicated in any way.

Comment: That problem is not related to dependencies. The error is `Dart snapshot generator failed`

Comment: I agree. It took me a while to narrow it down and I've reported it to the xml package owner. Is this something that should be reported on Dartlang.org too? Somewher else? I haven't found a defect in a tool before.

Comment: I think it's unrelated to the xml package and just a Dart compiler bug and should be reported in the  dart-lang/sdk repo-